# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' Angular

Tags: angular

i am creating the angular form design while i creating i got the error was **Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'** . i don't why i have import the formsmodule successfully why show us the error. what i tried so far i attached below.

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Student Name</label>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"    class="form-control"  id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" > 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Student Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="address" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" id="address" placeholder="Enter Address"> 
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Student Phone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="phone" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone"> 
      </div>

    <button type="submit" (click)="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule ,
    HttpClientModule,

   
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: It the module the one that bootstrap the main component or is it lazy loaded?

Comment: yes i attached the bootstrap style sheet as well

Comment: I believe then that you are using an Angular version > 12, if that's the case you should also include `ReactiveFormsModule`

Comment: Is the HTML in your app.component.html, or in an other component ? Can you show the full app.module.ts ?

Comment: app.component.html component

Comment: i did what you said ReactiveFormsModule  instead of  FormsModule but error not go away

Comment: i updated app.module.ts

Comment: ngModel is related to `FormsModule`, **not** to `ReactiveFormsModule` so you should import the FormsModule. BTW not use `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`. The use of this directive it's only if you're inside a FormGroup. Another thing: If use ngModel don't forget add  the attribute "name" to your inputs

Comment: Rememeber that when we add a new Module to our application, sometimes we need "re-start" the ng serve (Ctrl+C, and run again the command ng serve)

Comment: i done what you said <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"    class="form-control"  id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" >

Comment: i just removed the line [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" but error displayed

Comment: You need to have both `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`

Comment: thanks for your answer Jacopo Sciampi problem was solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import FormsModule also in AppModule file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule ,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,

   
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```